# Installing Unlocked Package in Production fails with conflicts

Tags: salesforcedx, platform-bug, unlocked-package

I have an **unlocked package** with custom object `Person__c` and field `Account__c` as a lookup on the account.

I tried installing this package in an org where `Person__c` object is already available with `Account__c` field it failed with the following error

> There is already a Child Relationship named **Persons** on Account.
>   **Person__c.Account__c**: There is already a Child Relationship named Persons on Account.

Is it the expected behavior or it is a platform bug?

I believed unlocked package could be used as a replacement of changeset or Ant-Migration tool as mentioned here : 
https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html

Comment: Does the unlocked package include the *relationship* field for the relationship? If not, this could cause problems. Without seeing your metadata, it'd be hard to know for sure. I have personally created unlocked packages with custom objects both as lookups and master-details to both standard and custom objects, and everything's worked fine. Could you possibly create a minimal copy of the metadata files so we could try it out ourselves? I know that's probably a huge ask, but it'd greatly help us help you if you could.

Comment: Could be the result of a modification in the relationship (e.g.: changing the type of relationship from lookup to master-detail) as well. The platform might try to create a new relationship with the same name. I'm just making a guess. OP can clarify if this is happening.

Comment: Did you activate Dev Hub and Unlocked Packages in this org?

Comment: Did you deploy `Person__c` with the field with another unlocked package?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for suggestions. I found that org has account lookup with slightly different field api name and same child relationship name. So the packaging field was not replacing the account lookup and it was conflicting with chield relationship name. 

Resolution: I just removed the old Account lookup field from a custom object and my package got installed.

Comment: @sushant You might want to add that as a answer to your question than just leaving it as comment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for suggestions. I found that org has account lookup with slightly different field **API name** but same **child relationship** name. So the packaging field was not replacing the account lookup and it was conflicting with child relationship name.

Resolution: I just removed the old Account lookup field from the custom object (in subscriber org) and my package got installed.